# how should i go about setting this buffer to expand automatically

Tags: c

i am currently rewriting a log parsing script from bash into C, and i was just wondering if i could get some advice regarding how i can set the array called buffer to expand dynamically instead of being limited to 1024, I think i would use malloc, but im not too sure how to properly implement it for this specific application, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
void main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  FILE *fd;
  char *name;
  name = getenv("MCEXEC_PLAYERNAME");
  char *filename;
  filename = malloc(sizeof "/home/minecraft/freedonia/playerdata/deathlog-.txt" - 1 +    strlen(name) + 1);
  if (!filename) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  sprintf(filename,"/home/minecraft/freedonia/playerdata/deathlog-%s.txt",name);
  char buff[1024];
  if ((fd = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL)
  {
    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

    while(!feof(fd))
    {
      memset(buff, 0x00, 1024);
      fscanf(fd, "%[^\n]\n", buff);
    }
    printf("%s\n", buff);
  }
  else
  printf( "fail" );
}
```

Comment: You actually need to use realloc() as soon as your buffer fills, have it grow by certain amount each time you fill it. Say +1024.

Comment: Just a quick note, if you are developing this cross platform then you should state that. Otherwise you may end up with a platform specific solution.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun: `malloc` and `realloc` are both in stdlib.h. This one should be pretty safe.

Comment: with the use of realloc that you had mentioned, how would i implement that for this specific application? my apologies if that is a dumb question (have just recently started teaching myself C and am making C version of some of my log parsing scripts in order to get the hang of common C functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to allocate the array dynamically.

If needed, [realloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) it to alter its size.

*EDIT:*

Instead of: `char buff[1024];`

use:

```
char *buff;
buff = malloc(1024); //This will allocate 1024 chars
```

You can use another variable like: `char tmp[256];` to read from file and store it into `buff`. As you put `tmp` into `buff`, keep note of the size of chars in `buff`. If necessary, make a call to realloc:

```
len = sizeof(buff);
buff = realloc(buff, len+256); //This will increase the buff size by 256
```

Comment: sorry to ask but with what you have described, how should i set this up concerning this specific example?

Comment: @lacrosse1991 Your asking how to use malloc & realloc?

Comment: More of just how i should implement it for this example, i am confused as to where i would call those funtions, should i add in realloc at the end of the while loop?

Comment: @lacrosse1991 Edited my answer. If you just want to print the contents of the file, you may `fgets()` as better option than `fscanf`.

Comment: awesome, should be very helpful :D and im assuming i would just put the len = sizeof(buff) buff = realloc(buff, len+256); in the end of the while loop? (am relatively new to C, my apologies if these questions should be obvious to me)

Comment: You can do that if you want to increase the size of buff for every iteration. As I said try to use `fgets` which is better for line-by-line reads.

Comment: neat, will have to look into using fgets for retrieving the last line of a file, seems like it could make things much easier!

Comment: sorry to keep dragging this on, but with memset, would i just set that to increase along with buff?

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your code that your are only trying to print the last line from the opened file.
You can just seek to the end of the file and search backwards for the second last '\n' and from that point onwards read upto 1024 bytes into your buffer at a time and print them on to the screen. You won't need a re-allocation for buff in this case.

EDIT : read upto 1023 each time into buff and let buff[1023] = '\0' always.